# Is the word driver used in this sense?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Driver - item used to drive objects away.

Use that *thingy* to drive away the birds.

Cows use their tails as a *driver* for flies.

The lady used some wand-like *driver* to drive away the supposed spirit inside of me.

Comment: That sort of makes sense but is.m not idiomatic; go for *Cows use their tails **to drive away** flies* instead.

Comment: No, "driver" is not used in the sense you describe.  The closest noun I can come up with is "repellant", though that is more often used in the sense of causing things to avoid the object rather than it being used to actively drive away things.  In the examples you cite, the word would typically be replaced by a specific noun to the situation, as one would use a "swatter" or "flyswatter" for flies and "ward" or "charm" for driving away spirits.

Comment: Cows use their tails to swat flies away.

Answer (score 0):

There are several definitions of the word *driver* such as [these](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/driver) from the Oxford Dictionary Online but yours does not seem to be among them.

If such definitions do exist they are probably specific uses or technical terms (the shamanic wand in your third example might well be called a driver by adherents of a particular shamanic cult for example) but are not part of normal idiomatic speech.

The normal term for the *thingy* in your first example would be a *bird scarer* or, possibly, *scarecrow*. One term for the use to which the cows put their tails would be *fly-whisk*.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think that you can you "[driver](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/driver)"  to suggest something that drives away something   else. The problem is that "driver" does not convey in itself the notion of the idiomatic expression "[drive away](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drive+away)".

The Free Dictionary